# My iOS 5 Beta 1 Expired! Now what?

Tags: ipod-touch, ios

I recently brought an iPod 4g. And one of my friend who was an iPhone application developer helped me upgrade my os to iOS 5 Beta 1. Now he is out of station and my iPod is locked.

I cannot do anything with my iPod.

Please advice me on how to degrade the OS to my previous version?

Thanks & Regards,

Comment: Does it show up in iTunes? How did it get locked?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Questions about pre-release software are off-topic for this site. See the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more details. Thanks.

Comment: Read the instructions Apple has posted on the developer forums on how you can get a newer beta. You will have to restore the device eventually when iOS 5 is eventually released, so you can wait for that or get a more current beta. This is how the betas work - it was clear this could happen in the release notes for that update.

Comment: Take this as a lesson, developer previews are, surprisingly, for developers; and preview and beta means not ready for release, in other words things like this will happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, [this is timely](http://www.tuaw.com/2011/08/16/psa-this-is-why-non-developers-shouldnt-run-ios-betas/).

Download the [iOS 4.3.5 iPod touch firmware image](http://appldnld.apple.com/iPhone4/041-1963.20110721.Huant/iPod4,1_4.3.5_8L1_Restore.ipsw), put your iPod touch in DFU mode, then use iTunes to restore to 4.3.5:

1. Launch iTunes.
2. Connect your iPod to your computer.
3. Shut it down by pressing and holding the power button for five seconds, then sliding to the right.
4. Press and hold the home and power buttons for ten seconds. Afterwards, release the power button, but continue to press the home button until iTunes detects the iPod.
5. If iTunes doesn't ask you for the file, <kbd>⌥</kbd>-click the **Restore** button. This should let you select the `.ipsw` file you have downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you can downgrade but try: Settings -> General -> Software Update ... there have been new Beta's so that might solve the problem.

Comment: Did you read the question? Its locked. I would downvote you but you only have 3 rep.

Comment: Ah, ok, point taken.

Comment: And Software Update didn't work until Beta 3.